# Filtering pandas Dataframe by value of one list of elements in one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am dealing with an API and when i convert the response to a pandas Dataframe, one of the columns has the following structure

**Api response**

```
"USER_ID": 00000,
"USER": "Sales",
"CUSTOMFIELDS": [
            {
                "FIELD_NAME": "CONTACT_FIELD_1",
                "FIELD_VALUE": "EN",
            },
            {
                "FIELD_NAME": "CONTACT_FIELD_10",
                "FIELD_VALUE": true,
            },
```

**Dataframe Column (list of dictionaries?)**

```
USER_ID   USER         CUSTOMFIELDS
10        Sales        [{'FIELD_NAME': 'CONTACT_FIELD_1', 'FIELD_VALU...
11        Production   [{'FIELD_NAME': 'CONTACT_FIELD_1', 'FIELD_VALU...
12        Market       [{'FIELD_NAME': 'CONTACT_FIELD_1', 'FIELD_VALU...
```

**1st row CUSTOMFIELDS column**

```
CUSTOMFIELDS
[{'FIELD_NAME': 'CONTACT_FIELD_1', 'FIELD_VALUE': 'EN'}, {'FIELD_NAME': 'CONTACT_FIELD_10', 'FIELD_VALUE': 'true'}, {'FIELD_NAME': 'CONTACT_FIELD_2', 'FIELD_VALUE': 'Contact'}]
```

**Goal**

Filter dataframe rows base on value of one of the elements in the CUSTOMFIELDS column. For example, get all dataframe rows equals to `'FIELD_NAME' = 'CONTACT_FIELD_10' and 'FIELD_VALUE = true'`

I am triying something like this but is not working

```
df = df_response[df_response.CUSTOMFIELDS.apply(lambda x: x['FIELD_NAME'] == 'CONTACT_FIELD_1')]
```

Thank you

Comment: not sure of the exact structure but if in each cell you have a list with 1 element being a dictionary, then try `df_response.CUSTOMFIELDS.str[0].str['FIELD_NAME']` to see if you can access the value corresponding to the key?

Comment: Thanks Ben, updated, meybe more clear now

Comment: can u share the data from the API? i feel it would be easier, and ultimately faster, to get the data into the various fields before reading into the dataframe

Comment: Hello sammywemmy, i am not sure what do u need, api response section of my post doesn't help you?

Answer (score 0):

this can be an alternative to validate on execution time:

```
df_response.loc[[True if val[0]['FIELD_NAME']=='CONTACT_FIELD_1' else False for (i,val) in df_response.CUSTOMFIELDS.iteritems()]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) on the CUSTOMFIELDS column, create a dataframe from it, [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) the values you want and use the index to select in your original dataframe.

```
# example df
df = pd.DataFrame({'user':[1,2], 
                   'CUSTOMFIELDS':[[{'FIELD_NAME':'CONTACT_FIELD_1', 'FIELD_VALUE':'EN'}, 
                                    {'FIELD_NAME':'CONTACT_FIELD_10', 'FIELD_VALUE':'true'}, 
                                    {'FIELD_NAME':'CONTACT_FIELD_2', 'FIELD_VALUE':'Contact'}], 
                                   [{'FIELD_NAME':'CONTACT_FIELD_1', 'FIELD_VALUE':'EN'}, 
                                    {'FIELD_NAME':'CONTACT_FIELD_10', 'FIELD_VALUE':'false'}, 
                                    {'FIELD_NAME':'CONTACT_FIELD_2', 'FIELD_VALUE':'Contact'}]]})

# define varirables to select
name = 'CONTACT_FIELD_10'
value = 'true'
# explode the column with a list in each cell
s = df['CUSTOMFIELDS'].explode()
# create the list of index to keep when any element of the list match your requirement
idx = pd.DataFrame(s.tolist(), s.index)\
        .query('FIELD_NAME==@name & FIELD_VALUE==@value')\
        .index.unique()

# select the index (could be reassign to df
df_f = df.loc[idx, :]
print (df_f)
   user                                       CUSTOMFIELDS
0     1  [{'FIELD_NAME': 'CONTACT_FIELD_1', 'FIELD_VALU...
```

Comment: Thanks Ben. T Not working.  Explode only removes list [{'FIELD_NAME': 'CONTACT_FIELD_1', 'FIELD_VALU to  {'FIELD_NAME': 'CONTACT_FIELD_1', 'FIELD_VALU

Comment: @Vince it may mean that what is inside the list is a string? can you check that?

Comment: Inside a list is a dictionaries. A list of dictionaries. {
                "FIELD_NAME": "CONTACT_FIELD_10",
                "FIELD_VALUE": "false",
                "CUSTOM_FIELD_ID": "CONTACT_FIELD_10"
            }

Comment: @Vince if it a list of dictionaries as I created in the example data, it should work. Can't help more with the information I have

Comment: Thanks @Ben. T, let me try your code again, sure it's my fault

Comment: @Vince not saying that ;) just that on my side with the information I have, I can't help more. Maybe I misunderstood our expected output? Does the result with the example data what you want? Otherwise, what is the name of the API you used?

Comment: I am using Insightly API 3.1. I'm editing later, i think it's not so clear. Thanks again @Ben. T